# Making for loop with index arrays faster

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following problem: I have index arrays with repeating indices and would like to add values to an array like this:

```
grid_array[xidx[:],yidx[:],zidx[:]] += data[:]
```

However, as I have repeated indices this does not work as it should because numpy will create a temporary array which results in the data for the repeated indices being assigned several times instead of being added to each other (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

A for loop like

```
for i in range(0,n):
    grid_array[xidx[i],yidx[i],zidx[i]] += data[i]
```

will be way to slow. Is there a way I can still use the vectorization of numpy? Or is there another way to make this assignment faster?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add an example to question?

Comment: By repeating, you mean some of the index pairs can be duplicates?  So you might get `grid_array(1,3,4) + data[3]+data[4}+data[10]`?

Comment: Exactly, some index pairs will be duplicate, and the case you described will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a buffering issue.  The `.at` provides unbuffered action
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html#numpy.ufunc.at

```
np.add.at(grid_array, (xidx,yidx,zidx),data)
```

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. This helped me a lot! And I think this answer is much better than the currently accepted one... In fact, if I ever get >= 150 points, I will award you 50 as a bounty! :)

Answer (score 3):

How about using bincount?

```
import numpy as np

flat_index = np.ravel_multi_index([xidx, yidx, zidx], grid_array.shape)
datasum = np.bincount(flat_index, data, minlength=grid_array.size)
grid_array += datasum.reshape(grid_array.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

For add an array to elements of a nested array you just can do `grid_array[::]+=data` :

```
>>> grid_array=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> data=np.array([3,3,3])
>>> grid_array[::]+=data
>>> grid_array
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: I think this is not what I was looking for, I wanted to add different data to a 3-D array.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a possible solution:

```
def assign(xidx,yidx,zidx,data):
    grid_array[xidx,yidx,zidx] += data
    return

map(assign,xidx,yidx,zidx,sn.part0['mass'])
```

Comment: `map` just hides the loop.

Comment: I guess it must be handled differently than the for loop, as it runs a lot faster.

Comment: In my small tests I don't get much difference in time with various looping constructs.

Comment: Using map for in place operations (often called side-effects) is a bad idea. If for no other reason, you should avoid it because in python3 map returns a generator and you'll need to write `for item in map(assign,xidx,yidx,zidx,sn.part0['mass']): pass` which is really ugly.